# Double space issue in R markdown text and code

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

I am working on an R markdown document and would like to use double spacing. I use the code

```
---
title: "smp"
author: "XXX YYY"
date: "October 9, 2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
---
```

However, It does not only double-spaces the text but also the code and the output. I do not want double space in the output. Is there any way to solve this? I attached a screenshot of the PDF output.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution at this link, https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/59565871.html. You can add `\singlespacing` before the each code block and `\doublespacing` after the code block to temporarily turn off double spacing.